Short novel involving a UFO crash and an alien hunter. Not "Stinger"
Getting ready to watch Teacup in a few weeks I re-read Stinger. In my mind, it had been replaced by another novel. I remembered Stinger as I got into it but there is a similar novel I need help finding. Maybe even a novella.
So a prison spaceship crashes, unleashing a violent alien that is female and needs to reproduce. Another alien, a hunter, arrives being sent from some space counsel to stop the first alien from laying eggs and destroying Earth. Alien hunter you'd say is the good guy, but we come to find out he has nefarious plans. The town is worried about fire, so I think it takes place in late 1800s or early 1900s. I think alien hunter passes himself off as black guy from Africa and is hunting this rare animal that got out of a zoo, obviously not telling people they are both aliens.
I read it in the last 5 years on Kindle but it was older probably from 80s or 90s. Not in Kindle history because I borrowed it and returned it. I remember the hunter Alien masquerading as an African bug game hunter and some locals trap it in a tenement building attic where it made a lair but it escapes and the local fire people are like throwing buckets of water so I know it takes place 100+ years ago.
Another section deals with how the original 1st creature was captured by a zookeeper after it crash landed because it was injured but it later killed all the tigers and escaped.

In roughly which year did you read this?

I read it in the last 5 years on Kindle but it was older probably from 80s or 90s. Not in kindle history because I borrowed it and returned it. I remember the hunter Alien masquerading as an African bug game hunter and some locals trap it in a tenement building attic where it made a lair but it escapes and the local fire people are like throwing buckets of water so I,know it takes place 100+ years ago.

Another section deals with how the original 1st creature was captured by a zookeeper after it crash landed because it was injured but it later killed all the tigers and escaped.

Does the alien look like a tiger? Is that why it was put into a cage in the zoo with other tigers?

No it was like an old time menagerie. Like a traveling zoo. They caught the alien soon after the crash because it was injured but as soon as it got Strong enough It just killed everybody and everything and escaped

nobody? Any idea where else to find out?
